# How to only show failing tests from behave?

Tags: python, acceptance-testing, python-behave

I've got a Python 3.4 project with tests built in the `behave` framework (version 1.2.5). When I run the tests, I get several hundred lines of output, most of it describing steps that passed with no problems. When a scenario fails, I need to scroll through all this output looking for the failure (which is easy to notice because it's red while the passing steps are green, but I still need to look for it).

Is there a way to make `behave` only show output for failing scenarios? Ideally, I'd have the output from all failing scenarios and the summary at the end of how many features/scenarios/steps were passed/failed/skipped. I'd also be content if it printed everything out but put all the failures at the bottom.

I've run `behave --help` and looked through [this website](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/), but didn't find anything relevant. and yet, surely I'm not the first person to get annoyed at this, and I imagine there's some way to do it. Thanks for the help!

edit: the `--quiet` flag simplifies the output, but does not remove it. For example, this output:

`Scenario Outline: Blank key identification -- @1.3 blank checks  # tests/features/tkg.feature:15
    Given we have pages with the wrong checksum                    # tests/features/steps/tkg_tests.py:30 0.000s
    When we check if the key is blank                              # tests/features/steps/tkg_tests.py:50 0.000s
    Then it is not blank                                           # tests/features/steps/tkg_tests.py:55 0.000s`

when run with the `--quiet` flag becomes:

`Scenario Outline: Blank key identification -- @1.3 blank checks 
    Given we have pages with the wrong checksum                    # 0.000s
    When we check if the key is blank                              # 0.000s
    Then it is not blank                                           # 0.000s`

but it's still the same number of lines long.

Comment: `--format progress` seems to not show that output but it also does not show it for failing tests. `--format progress2` shows the traceback for failing tests (but not that output) and so does `--format progress3`.

Comment: Yup, that'll do it! `--format` is much more powerful than I realized. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure what you wanted. I've posted that as an answer. Anyway it would be nice if there was a way to have also the step description together with the traceback of the failing test, but, AFAIK, there is no built-in formatter to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`--format`](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/behave.html#cmdoption--format) option with `progress` or `progress2` formatter.

This will not show the output for not failing tests (though it will still show the file names). The `progress2` option displays the traceback for the failing tests.